# Rails 5.2 AJAX with Partial Yielding JS Console Errors

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm attempting to make a task list with clickable check boxes that use AJAX when clicked.  Everything renders properly, but when clicked I get the following two JS console errors:

- A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
- "POST http://localhost:3000/tasks/1/task_uncomplete 500 (Internal
  Server Error)"

Here're my `tasks_controller.rb` methods:

```
  def task_complete
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    if @task.update_attributes(completed: true)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
      end
    else
      redirect_to redirect_back(fallback_location: tasks_path(@task))
      flash[:warning] = "Oops! Something went wrong!"
    end
  end



  def task_uncomplete
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    if @task.update_attributes(completed: false)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
      end
    else
      redirect_to redirect_back(fallback_location: tasks_path(@task))
      flash[:warning] = "Oops! Something went wrong!"
    end
  end
```

Here is where the partial lives:

```
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <h2 class="orange-text font-weight-bold">My Tasks</h2>
      <% tasks = Task.where(area_id: @area.id) %>
        <div id="tasks-list">
          <%= render partial: 'tasks/tasks-list', locals: { tasks: tasks } %>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- goals col -->
```

Here's the `tasks/_tasks-list.html.erb` partial:

```
<ul class="mb-0">
  <% tasks.each do |task| %>
    <% if task.completed %>
      <%= link_to task_uncomplete_path(task), method: :post, remote: true do %>
        <i class="far fa-check-square black-text" style="margin: 0 4px 0 -21px "></i>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to task.name, task_path(task), class: "black-text" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to task_complete_path(task), method: :post, remote: true do %>
        <i class="far fa-square black-text" style="margin: 0 4px 0 -21px "></i>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to task.name, task_path(task), class: "black-text" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to "+&nbsp;&nbsp;Create a New Task".html_safe, new_task_path, class: "orange-text", style: "margin-left: -19px" %>
</ul>
```

And here is `task_complete.js.erb` and `task_uncomplete.js.erb` (it's the same for both):

```
$("#tasks-list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tasks-list', locals: { tasks: tasks }) %>")
```

Finally, here are my relevant `routes.rb` paths:

```
  resources :tasks
  post "tasks/:id/task_complete" => "tasks#task_complete", as: "task_complete"
  post "tasks/:id/task_uncomplete" => "tasks#task_uncomplete", as: "task_uncomplete"
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**UPDATE**

At the advice of two potential answers, I updated it so `@tasks` is defined in the `areas_controller` like this:

```
  # GET /areas/1
  # GET /areas/1.json
  def show
    @goals = Goal.where(area_id: @area.id)
    @projects = Project.where(area_id: @area.id)
    @milestones = Milestone.where(area_id: @area.id)
    @tasks = Task.where(area_id: @area.id)
    @steps = Step.where(area_id: @area.id)
  end
```

The partial now looks like this:

```
<ul class="mb-0">
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <% if task.completed %>
      <%= link_to task_uncomplete_path(task), method: :post, remote: true do %>
        <i class="far fa-check-square black-text" style="margin: 0 4px 0 -21px "></i>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to task.name, task_path(task), class: "black-text" %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to task_complete_path(task), method: :post, remote: true do %>
        <i class="far fa-square black-text" style="margin: 0 4px 0 -21px "></i>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to task.name, task_path(task), class: "black-text" %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to "+&nbsp;&nbsp;Create a New Task".html_safe, new_task_path, class: "orange-text", style: "margin-left: -19px" %>
</ul>
```

And the updated `task_complete.js.erb` and `task_uncomplete.js.erb` (still the same for both) reads:

```
$("#tasks-list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tasks-list', locals: { tasks: @tasks }) %>")
```

The page renders properly with the updates, but I still have the same behavior (where it doesn't update asynchronously but does update when you refresh the page) and the following console error:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/tasks/1/task_complete 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: @user2490003 Added to the OP

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to verify the routes used `POST` - I always make the mistake of using `POST` when in reality it's `PATCH` or `PUT`. Seems you did that right. Are there any `before_action` filters that get run before these actions? It might be worth adding a `binding.pry` debugger at the start of the action to see a) if the execution ever reaches there instead of being redirected and b) whether the `request.format.to_sym` is `:json` (i.e the request is correctly specifying JSON as the response)

Comment: @user2490003 No `before_action` filters to speak of.  And if I put `binding.pry` before the `respond_to` and hit refresh it does actually update and I get a server error saying `NameError - undefined local variable or method 'tasks' for #<#<Class:0x00007faaa7ed2f98>:0x00007faa9784a870>
Did you mean?  @task:
  app/views/tasks/task_complete.js.erb:1:in '_app_views_tasks_task_complete_js_erb__2838412480520202554_70185331612120'`.  Any ideas what that means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task_uncomplete.js.erb and task_complete.js.erb  don't have instance variable named tasks or @tasks defined.

if you see your partial. here

```
<%= render partial: 'tasks/tasks-list', locals: { tasks: tasks } %>
```

you have tasks defined with

```
<% tasks = Task.where(area_id: @area.id) %>
```

where as Ajax call don't have @tasks or tasks. you need to define that in controller or in js.erb before you render. to define @tasks, i understand you need area. you need to preserve area value throughout your ajax call

Comment: I made this change (see details in the updated OP) but am still experiencing the same behavior.  Thoughts?

Comment: You will need to add @tasks in task_uncomplete method and not in show method. As your ajax call is rendered from task_uncomplete method

Comment: Unfortunately, adding `@tasks = Task.where(area_id: @area.id)` in my `task_uncomplete` method didn't change the behavior at all.

Comment: is this still open. If yes. can you please post exact error message. updated error message

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be coming from this part of your `task_complete.js.erb` and `task_uncomplete.js.erb`.

```
... locals: { tasks: tasks })
```

tasks is undefined... I believe it should be an instance variable from your controller. Maybe you meant to write:

```
locals: { tasks: @tasks })
```

Comment: I made this change (see details in the updated OP) but am still experiencing the same behavior.  Thoughts?